Помогите с Java Script, легкое
const newPost = (post, addedAt = Date()) => {

...post,
    addedAt,
    return post
}
const postOne = {
    id: 1,
    author: 'rofler2005'
}
newPost(postOne)

ошибка

declaration or statement expected.

почему? если я ставлю круглые скобки вместе с фигурными в функции,
то все нормально, но если я хочу вернуть с помощью return, как поступить?

А что значит `{
...post,
addedAt,
return post
}` ??? Не смогли определиться return или всё же не return?

я очень плохо разбираюсь, return нужно, но почему то с ним ошибка

return нужен для возвращения значения из функции...допустим, а что за перечисления через запятую и ... перед post?

три точки вроде разделяет на свойства

какие свойства? свойства чего?

свойства объекта


как поступить?

Если хотите вернуть объект, при этом в стрелочной функции, то надо оборачивать в круглые скобочки. При этом никакие return post уже не нужно, т.к. при конструкции => ({  }) уже будет применён return.
Почему в данном случае нужны круглы скобки? Потому что возвращается объект, который обычно обозначается через фигурные скобки, но и в стрелочных функциях фигурные скобки означают, что будет тело функции и потом возврат значения через return. Получается конфликт парсинга. Не ясно к чему относятся фигурные скобки. Чтобы интерпретатор мог однозначно понять, что это именно возврат объекта, а не скобки, которые относятся к телу функции - люди, через лайфхак, оборачивают этот объект в круглые скобки. Они ни на что не влияют, только дают пониманию интерпретатору, что это уже не фигурные скобки функции, а что-то другое.
Либо можно писать понятнее для интерпретатора, т.е.:
=> {
    return {
        ...post,
        addedAt,
    }
}

